# Angular throws "Error: Invalid argument." in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which takes element's text and places [wbr](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_wbr.asp) elements after every 10th character. I'm using it for example on table cells with long text (e.g. URLs), so it does not span over the table. Code of the directive:

```
myApp.directive('myWbr', function ($interpolate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // get the interpolated text of HTML element
            var expression = $interpolate(element.text());

            // get new text, which has <wbr> element on every 10th position
            var addWbr = function (inputText) {
                var newText = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++) {
                    if ((i !== 0) && (i % 10 === 0)) newText += '<wbr>'; // no end tag
                    newText += inputText[i];
                }
                return newText;
            };

            scope.$watch(function (scope) {
                // replace element's content with the new one, which contains <wbr>s
                element.html(addWbr(expression(scope)));
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Works fine except in IE (I have tried IE8 and IE9), where it throws an error to the console: `Error: Invalid argument.`

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UZbk/1/), when clicking on the button you can see the error in console.

So obvious question: why is the error there, what is the source of it, and why only in IE?

(Bonus question: how can I make IE dev tools to tell me more about error, like the line from source code, because it took me some time to locate it, `Error: Invalid argument.` does not tell much about the origin.)

P.S.: I know IE does not know the wbr at all, but that is not the issue.

**Edit:** in my real application I have re-written the directive to not to look on element's text and modify that, but rather pass the input text via attribute, and works fine now in all browsers. But I'm still curious why the original solution was giving that error in IE, thus starting the bounty.

Comment: jsFiddle doesn't work in old IE (at least the editor), so I'm not sure how you're even testing in IE 8. Try visiting http://jsfiddle.net/5UZbk/1/show/ (note I added "show/" to the end of the URL) - it works fine for me in IE 8

Comment: [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_wbr.asp) it says that `<wbr>` is *not* supported in any IE. May be the cause (or it may not, just in case it may be helpful).

Comment: @Ian I tested my real application with IE8 and IE9. jsFiddle I created in other browser and then the link to it opens fine in IE9 (well with the error I described)

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos no that is not the problem (last line in my question)

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos sorry I used wrong markup on the last line, so it was not visible whole

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your attempt to create a directive to inject  elements into your string runs into a known bug in IE dealing `appendChild` method. I was able to reproduce your error IE with your fiddle even after removing the `<div>` appending completely.

Notice, that if you remove your `div` concatenation completely, and attempt to return `newText` in original form, you still get

> Error: Invalid argument.

[Transclusion on UI view not working on IE9-10-11](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/615)

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5UZbk/4/) is the very same code, just `<wbr>` changed to `<div>` - still throws error in IE

Comment: @przno, this is a known bug **On IE9-10-11 if you put some html content into an ui-view directive, the content is correctly shown at the first attempt, but not when you come back to the same status. The same code works fine on Firefox and Chrome** https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/615

Comment: @DaveA Please don't link w3schools! It's completely unrelated to W3C (your link is misleading), and often is wrong, inaccurate, and outdated. See [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) for more info. [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) is much better.

Comment: @Oriol, thanks for the link. info is useful and interesting. but please don't use **!!!** 's to comment. It gives the impression that my answer is wrong or misleading when the W3C link is a small section of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My `"error invalid argument anonymous function call"` was being thrown from me doing the following on the code below.

Error:

```
<span data-ng-bind="name.first">{{name.first}}</span>
```

No Error:

```
<span data-ng-bind="name.first"></span>
```

Comment: same for ng-bind-html

Answer (score 0):

Not an Angular answer (and an old question, I know), but I'd suggest you might be taking the wrong approach to the problem. Rather insert  breaks (which would ruin any markup in the string for example), simply use the CSS text-overflow or overflow property.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in IE when I had following error in HTML template:

```
<textarea disabled  [(ngModel)]="some.var">{{some.var}}</textarea>
```

**disabled** textarea does not allow ngModel in IE

Chrome, FF did not complain, just IE Edge.
It is a good idea, to check the template too

Comment: Note that this question regards AngularJS, not Angular 2+.